# Multiple PHP variables in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

I'm trying to edit some PHP code I recieved which fetches data from a mysql database, it is essentially getting data and formatting it into a json object. The query use a php variable called "start". What I can't get to work is to make it consider another variable in the php file in the mysql query called `klass`, it just returns an empty json array when I add it, indicating there is something wrong with the query passed to the database.

**Here is the original code:**

```
<?php

include_once 'db.php';
//getting the varibles into PHP

$start = 0;
if(isset($_GET['start'])) {
     $start = $_GET['start'];
}

if(isset($_GET['klass'])) {
 $klass= $_GET['klass'];
}
//sql statement
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column2` > 0 ORDER BY `column1` ASC LIMIT :start ,30";

$stmt = $pdb->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':start', (int) $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

//putting data into array
$data = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
 $data[] = array(
      'id' => $row['id'],
      'column1' => $row['column1'],
      'column2' => $row['column2'], 
      'column3' => $row['column3'],
      'column4' => $row['column4'],
      'column5' => $row['column5']
      );
 $start++;
}

//send back data in json format
echo json_encode(array('nextAmt' => $start, 'laxor' => $data));
?>
```

This works perfectly fine and works great, and sends the correct data back to the javascript jquery.post function.

**But I've tried to just add a PHP varible into the query like this:**

```
//sql statement

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column2` > 0 AND `klass` = " . $klass . "ORDER BY `column1` ASC LIMIT :start ,30";
```

**And using another binValue like this**

```
//sql statement

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column2` > 0 AND `klass` = :klass ORDER BY `column1` ASC LIMIT :start ,30";

$stmt = $pdb->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':start', (int) $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':klass', (str) $klass, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

And none of them seems to be working, i don't think that the "klass" varible gets inserted into the query correctly.

How should i do it in the right way?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your output something like this? Say when start = 30
`{"nextAmt":30,"laxor":[]}`

Comment: To be honest, best way to debug it, is examine wholly manufactured query by echoing `$stmt->queryString` prior to `$stmt->execute()`. Could you please do it and show the result query?

Comment: I told about debugging a version where you use `bindValue` for both `start` and `klass`

Comment: Please be more specific about "none of them seems to be working."  What does "not working" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, on this one you are missing a whitespace after $klass variable, I fixed it for you here

```
//sql statement

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column2` > 0 AND `klass` = {$klass} ORDER BY `column1` ASC LIMIT {$start} ,30";
```

Comment: you can parametrize the LIMIT if you cast it to (int). in PHP 5.3 or higher you have to use intval()

Answer (score 0):

String need to be in quote like for

```
`klass` = " . $klass . "
```

you should use

```
`klass` = '" . $klass . "'
```

for all string you need to add quote.

Comment: it seems like klass is also an int value :) he also cast and bind it as int. so the quotes are not needed

Answer (score 0):

```
`klass` = " . $klass . "ORDER BY `column1`
                        ^ You have missed a whitespace after end of double quote
```

Replace your query with this one

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` 
  WHERE `column2` > 0 AND `klass` = " . $klass . " 
  ORDER BY `column1` ASC LIMIT :start ,30";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last way is correct. Is `$klass` actually an numerical value? if not, try `PDO::PARAM_STR` instead of `PDO::PARAM_INT` and remove the `(int)` cast.

You are already using prepared statements, so stay with it and **don't** add PHP variables directly. You are opening your script for SQL injections again.

Comment: It is a string thanks for noticing, though it is still not working

Answer (score 0):

Bad thing is, you're setting `$klass` only when is set `$_GET['klass']`, but use it in any situation no matter is defined or not.

I'm sure your result query is something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE 
    `column2` > 0 AND 
    `klass` = 0 
ORDER BY `column1` ASC 
LIMIT 0 ,30
```

It is little trick in php: `(int)` for undefined variable returns `0` (and you did this trick in `bindValue` — `(int) $klass`). For example:

```
$a = (int)$b;
echo $a;
//Outputs 0, even if $b was not defined. No errors/warnings
```

So, you trying to get all rows where `klass` is `0`. I think you have no records in the table where `klass` is zero. As a result, you've received empty result.

I would rewrite your code in this manner:

```
$klass_piece = isset($klass) ? ' AND `klass` = :klass' : '';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column2` > 0" . $klass_piece . " ORDER BY `column1` ASC LIMIT :start ,30";

$stmt = $pdb->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':start', (int) $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);

if (isset($klass)) {
    $stmt->bindValue(':klass', (int) $klass, PDO::PARAM_INT);
}

$stmt->execute();
```